Method for detecting a table from an image and cutting out and storing only the table

Hello. I need some help. I want to work on extracting only the white mark part from the attached image.
My idea is My idea was to recognize and cut RGB 255, 255, 255 based on RGB 255, 255.
Unfortunately, however, it works well in some cases but not well in some cases.
Here's the code, and if there's anything that needs to be modified, please let me know.
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

input_folder =
output_folder = 

if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
os.makedirs(output_folder)

for filename in os.listdir(input_folder):
img_path = os.path.join(input_folder, filename)
image = cv2.imread(img_path)

if image is not None:
    brightened_image = cv2.convertScaleAbs(image, alpha=1.2, beta=20)

    lower_white = np.array([253, 253, 253], dtype=np.uint8)
    upper_white = np.array([255, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.inRange(brightened_image, lower_white, upper_white)

    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    if contours:
        largest_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(largest_contour)
        
             cropped_image = brightened_image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

              output_img_path = os.path.join(output_folder, filename)
        cv2.imwrite(output_img_path, cropped_image)
    else:
        print(f"No contours found for {filename}")
else:
    print(f"Could not load image {filename}")


"only the white mark part"  do you mean the white text box in the bottom right corner or something else ?

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

I mean white text box in the bottom right corner. Sorry  I'll upload the full code. Thank you for your help.

Your image appears to contain no colour information so you can discard it by using cv.imread(..., cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) and save RAM and processing time/complexity. I would suggest using cv.normalize(..., MINMAX) to normalize to a range of 0..255 instead of applying arbitrary gain and bias.
